# How can I select bottom row from second table using inner join in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000

How can I select bottom row from second table using inner join from two tables?

Here `[customer records]` contains customer details and photoinfo contains photodetails.

```
SELECT 
    CR.customernumber, CR.customername, 
    CR.Addressline1, CR.city, CR.state, 
    CR.pincode, CR.landline, CR.mobile, 
    CR.dob, CR.gender,
    PR.FileName, CR.remarks, CR.fulladdress, CR.regno,
    CR.qualification, CR.bg, CR.fname, 
    CR.field1, CR.field2, CR.field3, CR.field4, CR.field5,       
    CR.sign 
from 
    [customer records] CR
inner join 
    photoinfo PR on PR.customernumber = CR.customernumber
where 
    CR.customernumber >= 5050 and CR.customernumber <= 5100
order by 
    CR.customernumber
```

Here filename is text field from photoinfo. i need to select every last row of filename from photoinfo

Thanks in advance

**Customer records**

```
cnumber cname             Mobile       Gender
2000    K.Deepalakshmi                  F
2001    J.Geetha         9789426497     F
```

**photoinfo**

```
cid     cnumber  Filename
5152    2000     B6216.jpg
5153    2001     B6203.jpg
5154    2001     B6209.jpg
5155    2001     B6205.jpg
```

here i want join the above two tables based on cnumber(customernumber). and i want join last or the first filename from photoinfo based on cid like.

**expected output**

```
cnumber cname            filename   Mobile       Gender
2000    K.Deepalakshmi   B6216.jpg                F
2001    J.Geetha         B6205.jpg  9789426497    F
```

Comment: Could you post some some data ..or try using `partition by` clause

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114: all those nice features like `PARTITION BY` are **NOT** available in the ancient SQL Server **2000** version....

Comment: my bad! i missed the `tags`

Answer (score -1):

**Create & insert Customer table**

```
create table #customer(cnumber decimal(18,0),cname varchar(100),Mobile  varchar(100),Gender varchar(1))

insert into #customer values
(2000,'K.Deepalakshmi','','F'),
(2001,'J.Geetha','9789426497','F')
```

**Create & Insert Photo info table**

```
create table #photoinfo(cid decimal(18,0),cnumber decimal(18,0),filename varchar(100))

insert into #photoinfo values
(5152,2000,'B6216.jpg'),
(5153,2001,'B6203.jpg'),
(5154,2001,'B6209.jpg'),
(5155,2001,'B6205.jpg')
```

**Result**

```
select c.cnumber,c.cname,p.filename,c.Mobile,c.Gender
from #customer c
join #photoinfo p on p.cnumber=c.cnumber
join (select c.cnumber,max(p.cid) cid
    from #customer c
    join #photoinfo p on p.cnumber=c.cnumber
    group by c.cnumber) r on r.cnumber=p.cnumber and p.cid=r.cid
```